# t4 templte is located outside of directory of target project

Tags: c#, t4

at  one solution,t4 template file was in Frame.Model  project

```
var path = solutionPath+@"\Frame.Service\Interface\"+config.FileName;
config.Output.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
config.RenderToFile(path);
```

This will generate code to another project,but wrong,
message:

```
*13 Output file D:\Code\Frame.Web\Frame.Service\Interface\IUser.generated.cs is located outside of directory of target project 

D:\Code\Frame.Web\Frame.Model\Frame.Model.csproj    
D:\Code\Frame.Web\Frame.Model\T4\EntityCodeScript.tt 1 1 Frame.Model*
```

when I change to:

```
var path = solutionPath+@"\Frame.Model\Interface\"+config.FileName;
```

That successes,   why can't generate file in diffrence project?
how do?  thk!!!

sorry  i am  enlish is very bad  , i hope you can know  whats this

Answer (score 0):

you need to add template.Output.Project. check this article .
http://www.olegsych.com/2009/03/t4-toolbox-generating-files-in-different-folders-and-projects/